# How do I get buttons to appear in android xml layout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add two buttons to the bottom of the screen in my layout file.  Everything compiles and runs fine but I don't see the two buttons.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/UrlText"
    android:hint="Enter URL"
    android:layout_width="600px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone">

    <requestFocus />

</EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="X" />
```

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B"
    android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="F"
    android:id="@+id/buttonForward"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Because your web view is set to match_parent. Adjust the height of your webview and you will see it. Or may be use weight for them.

Comment: Your WebView android:layout_height="match_parent" fills the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes in your `WebView`, change `layout_height` and add `layout_weight`

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Replace the code for buttons with this:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="B"
android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 />

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="F"
android:id="@+id/buttonForward"
 android:layout_weight="1"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, simple and elegant.  The one thing I forgot to mention in my original post was that I want to place the buttons side by side.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Change you height match_parent to wrap_content.

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Or put your webview and buttons in a ScrollView with a height of "wrap_content"

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
Buttons and webview
</ScrollView
```

Answer (score 0):

Your webview is already filling all the available space, try using a relative layout and position your views inside it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttonBar">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="B"
            android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="F"
            android:id="@+id/buttonForward"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```